# FBA User Management is really slow and the search on it not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, forms-authentication

I'm having a problem with my FBA in production  envirement, when I choose the "**FBA User Management**" option  it tooks a lot of time to respond (I have just 20 000 users)...
But when we choose to find a specific (Search) user it tooks a huge amount of time and share point goes down showing "Sorry somthing went wrong" with an Id of correlation

*Logs :*

Failed to read resource file "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Resources\FBAPackFeatures.fr-FR.resx" from feature id "(null)".

Failed to open the language resource keyfile FBAPackFeatures.
[Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 05/16/2018 10:38:19.79, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.110053998923011

Application error when access /_layouts/15/FBA/Management/UsersDisp.aspx, Error=Time out

System.Web.HttpException: time out

I have share point 2013, running on windows server 2012

Any Ideas please

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest version of the FBA Pack.  The slowdown was fixed in the last version of the FBA Pack - 1.3.6:

https://www.visigo.com/products/sharepoint-fba-pack/version-history/